# Store all element which are hidden to hide again later

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I, using the each function, find all the elements within another, log all the class names of each element;

```
<div class="Actions">
    <div class="Trash"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    <div class="Mark-Read"><i class="fa fa-envelope-open-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    <div class="Flag"><i class="fa fa-flag" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    <div class="Pin"><i class="fa fa-thumb-tack" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
</div>

// My progress...
$(this).find('.Actions').children().not(":visible").each(....);
```

And then at a later point, hide all of those elements?

I simply use `$(this).find('.Actions').children().show();` elsewhere to show all the elements however later on those elements which were initially hidden need to be rehdden.

Comment: I would simply have a class for that which controls the visibility of the element (*in this case it hides them*). This way you can find them by class.

Comment: Why would you need all the classNames, couldn't you just target `$('[aria-hidden="true"]')` etc.

Comment: when you say later do you mean on page refresh or later as in when a button is clicked later in the code/page flow?

Comment: Some  messages show the `.Pin` and `.Flag` as they've been pinned and/or flagged. It is only the initial four at the moment. If they aren't shown, `.Active` hover shows them all and then hides them when hover out. Whereas some are already shown, the ones which are need to stay and the hover shown ones need to be hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a working snippet with what you have expected.

Basically, an `attribute` has added to the element to have a reference if it was hidden initially.

Then using the same attribute, it has been set hidden when the "Reset" button clicked.

```js
$('.Actions').children().not(':visible').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('data-display', 'none');
});

$('.Actions').children().show();

$('#reset').click(function(){
  $('.Actions').children('[data-display="none"]').hide();
});
```

```css
.Flag
{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Actions">
    <div class="Trash"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    <div class="Mark-Read"><i class="fa fa-envelope-open-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    <div class="Flag"><i class="fa fa-flag" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    <div class="Pin"><i class="fa fa-thumb-tack" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
</div>
<input id="reset" type="button" value="Reset">
```